# Sum all values of array objects and merge the objects if inquiry number is same

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have an object and inside is array of objects, I want to merge the objects which have same `InquiryNo` and inside I want to add the `Quantity` (first convert it to integer and then add) and concatenate `ProductDesc` with `', '`. I tried doing it but I am getting wrong sums and some wrong `ProductDesc` values. This is what I have done so far:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.data.length; i++) {
    obj.data[i].Quantity = parseInt(obj.data[i].Quantity);
}

console.log(typeof(obj.data[0].Quantity));

var data = obj.data, result = data.reduce(function (hash) {
    return function (r, a) {
        var key = a.InquiryNo;
        if (!hash[key]) {
            hash[key] = {
                ColorCode: a.ColorCode,
                CustCode: a.CustCode,
                CustomerName: a.CustomerName,
                InquireDate: a.InquireDate,
                InquiryNo: a.InquiryNo,
                LeadTime: a.LeadTime,
                PatternCode: a.PatternCode,
                Post: a.Post,
                PostStatus: a.PostStatus,
                ProductDesc: a.ProductDesc,
                QualityCode: a.QualityCode,
                Quantity: a.Quantity,
                ShipDate: a.ShipDate,
                StyleCode: a.StyleCode,
                Unit: a.Unit
            };
            r.push(hash[key]);
            console.log(hash[key]);
        }
        hash[key].Quantity += a.Quantity;
        return r;
    };
}(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result[0].Quantity);
```

And this is the object that I am trying to fight with:

```
var obj = {
    meta: {
        page: "1",
        pages: "1",
        perpage: "-1",
        total: 114,
        sort: "asc",
        field: "InquiryNo"
    },
    data: [
        {
            InquiryNo: 38090,
            Quantity: "27000",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "2/6/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Hand Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38090,
            Quantity: "27000",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "2/6/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Bath Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38090,
            Quantity: "27000",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "2/6/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Wash Cloth"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38090,
            Quantity: "27000",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "2/6/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Bath Sheett5"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38090,
            Quantity: "27000",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "2/6/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Non Terry Kitchen Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38090,
            Quantity: "27000",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "2/6/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Window Pane Solid KT"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38303,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Hand Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38303,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Bath Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38303,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Wash Cloth"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38303,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Bath Sheett5"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38303,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Non Terry Kitchen Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38303,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Window Pane Solid KT"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38304,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Hand Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38304,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Bath Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38304,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Wash Cloth"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38304,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Bath Sheett5"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38304,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Non Terry Kitchen Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38304,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Window Pane Solid KT"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38305,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Hand Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38305,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Bath Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38305,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Wash Cloth"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38305,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Bath Sheett5"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38305,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Non Terry Kitchen Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38305,
            Quantity: "10",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "8/1/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Window Pane Solid KT"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38309,
            Quantity: "50000",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 27,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "11/27/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Hand Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38309,
            Quantity: "50000",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 27,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "11/27/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Bath Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38309,
            Quantity: "50000",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 27,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "11/27/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Wash Cloth"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38309,
            Quantity: "50000",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 27,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "11/27/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Bath Sheett5"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38309,
            Quantity: "50000",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 27,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "11/27/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Non Terry Kitchen Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38309,
            Quantity: "50000",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 27,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "11/27/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Window Pane Solid KT"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38312,
            Quantity: "1260",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "12/9/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Hand Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38312,
            Quantity: "1260",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "12/9/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Hand Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38312,
            Quantity: "1260",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "12/9/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Hand Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38312,
            Quantity: "1260",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "12/9/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Hand Towel"
        },
        {
            InquiryNo: 38312,
            Quantity: "473",
            QualityCode: null,
            ColorCode: null,
            PatternCode: null,
            StyleCode: null,
            Post: "U",
            PostStatus: null,
            CustCode: 0,
            Unit: 1,
            CustomerName: "WAL-MART STORES INC.",
            InquireDate: "12/9/2017",
            LeadTime: null,
            ShipDate: null,
            ProductDesc: "Terry Hand Towel"
        }
    ]
};
```

Let me know if I need to explain something else, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the `-1` in `i < obj.data.length - 1`? You want to intentionally omit the last element?

Comment: @connexo no I was checking something in b/w that's a typo... thanks for letting me know. I have edited the question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I able to do it:

```
let result = [];

obj.data.forEach(function(obj) {
    let id = obj.InquiryNo;
    // converting quantity type from string to integer
    obj.Quantity = parseInt(obj.Quantity);
    if(!this[id]) {
        result.push(this[id] = obj);
    } else {
        this[id].Quantity += parseInt(obj.Quantity);
        this[id].InquireDate += `, ${obj.InquireDate}`;
        this[id].ProductDesc += `, ${obj.ProductDesc}`;
    }
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do this with a for loop and some lodash utils myself, but a problem in your code is that you always add the `a.Quantity`, even for a newly added `key`. Using an `else` clause should fix that.

```
            ..
            console.log(hash[key]);
        } else {
          hash[key].Quantity += a.Quantity;
          // code for ProductDesc 
        }
        return r;
        ..
```